# Share compiled dependencies between dev and release builds

Tags: performance, rust, compilation, rust-cargo

I can compile Rust dependencies in optimized mode, while compiling your own code in debug mode:

```
# Cargo.toml
[profile.dev.package."*"]
opt-level = 3
debug = false
```

But this still compiles all my dependencies twice: once for debug mode and once for release mode, which seems wasteful (even with sccache):

```
$ cargo clean
$ cargo build
... all the dependencies ...
Finished dev [unoptimized + debuginfo] target(s) in 1m 44s
$ cargo build --release
... all the dependencies ...
Finished release [optimized] target(s) in 2m 08s
```

Theoretically it's only once, but in reality there are multiple developers, clean builds, cicd pipelines...

How can I make dev mode and release mode share compiled targets?

Comment: After the initial compilation, incremental builds would be much faster. Why is this a concern?

Comment: @sshashank124 "in reality there are […], clean builds, cicd pipelines" CI/CD typically does clean builds, if he is compiling in both release and debug mode there, he might be afraid to waste resources.